# Segue Identifier is going missing in Swift 5.6

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, segue, viewcontroller

I've only been programming for a month, and I am trying to cobble together a mockup and I keep getting the following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:  'Receiver (<OutsizeMockup_0_1.HomeViewController: 0x13460f870>) has no segue with identifier 'testSegue''

I get this when I have my segue transition:
`self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToProducts", sender: self)`
within my buttonWasPressed method(which is called after my URLSession is created), but not when I call it within any other button that's not nested in Session. So I know the identifier is spelled correctly and under the right view controller class. I'll post my code below.

[My project layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQNrk.png)

First the browse button is pressed and the fetchDrop method is called:

[HomeViewController where button is pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucUAq.png)

Then, the class that manages the url session is called: [DropManager class with url session. Using this data, pM.initializeProducts is called, leading to the next file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJA1t.png)

[Finally, buttonIsPressed is called here. And once it's called, the segue within the HomeViewController gets the error that I mentioned above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiPAj.png)

I'd be interested to know if there are any glaring issues with my code.

Comment: to clarify, my segue works perfectly as long as I call it BEFORE fetchDrop is called. Everything else being the same.

Comment: Please review [ask] -- specifically, do not post **images of code** ... post your actual code in your question. In one of your images, you have the comment *"// delegate wasn't working..."* -- you need to figure out why (but you didn't show your `buttonWasPressed` func anywhere. Your attempt to do something different creates a **new** instance of `HomeViewController` - it does ***NOT*** give you a reference to the existing `HomeViewController`

Comment: @DonMag ah I'm sorry, now I know... and the issue did end up being that I was creating a new instance of the view controller! Thank you so much.